# AS3 : how can i use sprites with green background in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite

I noticed that many of the sprites on the internet has a solid color background and not transparent i am sure there is a reason behind that but what is it ?

like this one :

http://www.spriters-resource.com/gameboy_advance/gs2/sheet/47045

I can remove the bg using photoshop but if this was the purpose why people didn't save it as transparent png in the first place.

what is the easier way to use this sprites in flash it doesn't make sense to me to cut each one and put it in a separate frame i am sure there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Sprite sheets are not meant to be sliced up into different images before compilation. Rather, they are mainly used for a technique called blitting which involves copying the pixels from the spritesheet onto the display at runtime (traditionally done for a performance gain over the standard Flash display list rendering).

You can read up on blitting here: http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/7/2/Tutorial-AS3-The-basics-of-tile-sheet-animation-or-blitting/

And on how to actually remove the background when blitting: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/animation/blitting-with-as3-removing-a-bitmaps-background-color/

Comment: Thanks for this helpful info . great i didn't know that before very good tutorial